# How to deny a user to access (select, insert, delete, update) to tables but grant (select) a few

Tags: sql-server, table, role

i am trying to deny a user to access (select, insert, delete, update) to tables on my database but i also need him to grant only select to a few tables,
to do this i created a user with login and gave him datareader permission then by using the code below i Denied user to Select data from a table,

```
DENY SELECT ON "dbo"."Customer" TO "test"
```

He can't see the table which is fine but he can still select the data by

```
select * from Customer
```

what i want is to deny select data from table, i don't care whether he sees the table.

for further step i will deny users to access tables but few views.

here is the image;
[image: screen shot]

[image: not owner]

[image: system user]

[image: for sepupic]

Comment: That user should not be able to select from the table. Are you sure he is selecting from dbo.Customer and not a table with the same name but a different schema (not dbo).

Comment: i am sure, there is a test database which has only one schema and also user has access only to that database.

Comment: Under this user execute the following code: select * from sys.fn_my_permissions('your_table', 'object'), what permissions does it show?

Comment: ...And why do you enclose everything in double quotes???

Comment: @sepupic i added as a picture.

Comment: From the image you posted your user is at least db_owner

Comment: @RandiVertongen tried that also, no hope

Comment: Under this user please check select is_srvrolemember('sysadmin')

Comment: @sepupic not owner what is the thing i am doing it wrong ? select is_srvrolemember('sysadmin') returns 1

Comment: ...And update your question with the result ofselect system_user, user

Comment: Your user is sysadmin and there is no way to deny to him

Comment: @sepupic how can i correct it ? it should be a just a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "secret" here is that your `login` test is `sysadmin` and he's mapped to `dbo` in every `database`. `Test user` that is on your picture is NOT the `user` corresponding to login "test".

If you want to execute under user `test` you should write the code

```
exec as login = 'test'
select *
from customer
revert
```

And this user will have the deny on `customer` table.

But now all the code you executed you executed it under `dbo` user (that corresponds to `test` login), this can be proved by executing

```
select system_user, user
```

that will show `test` as `system_user` and `dbo` as `user`.

This situation can happen if the login (test) was mapped to this database when he was not `sysadmin`, so `test` user was created. But then someone made him `sysadmin` and now he is mapped to dbo and `test` is just orphaned.

Another situation is when `databas`e was restored and that `user` (still orphaned) has no corresponding login, the new `test` login is not related to it and is mapped to `dbo`

> how can i correct it ? it should be a just a user

```
exec sp_dropsrvrolemember 'test', 'sysadmin'
```

This way you make him an ordinary login.

Then you should check if your user test is his corresponding login or just re-map it:

```
alter user test with login = test;
```

---

**UPDATE**

Assuming that the first screenshot is shown "as is" it seems that **the code to test "Check if it still works"** **was executed under the same account that denied the `select` permission, i.e. under `sa` login** as there is no code impersonating `test` login. This explains because the `select` code was executed without errors and also the result of `select system_user, user` confirms this.

Comment: Dear Sepupic i really appreciate your help, the thing is i created user, no one has access to my local database, so no one can change the ownership etc. and the user is not orphaned, many times i deleted and re-created user to understand what is wrong, when i created user i just gave him datareader permission nothing more but still no hope, i also run the commands you gave, it did not change anything.

Comment: @washaq please update your question with the result of select system_user, user (executed under the test login)

Comment: it is still same as in system user image

Comment: In your image the code is executed as "sa". I asked you about system_user, user **executed under test login**

Comment: @washaq SSMS shows your login in the status bar. Make sure you execute the code under **test** login. If SSMS still shows you "sa" execute the code with **exec as login = 'test'**

Comment: i did as you asked it is the same. i executed the command under test login.

Comment: @washaq, if you really executed under **test** login the result for system_user would be **test**, not **sa**. Please attach another screenshot to your question where you execute  select system_user, user under test login with the SSMS **status bar** on it

Comment: now i got it i logged in with test but on status bar it says sa, hold on a minute please.

Comment: i added picture, is it all because of i am staying on the same query windows i used with login sa?

Comment: yep it is because of that, i am so sorry it is all my fault, i took your time. i really appreciated your help.